# how to set checkbox checked based on value in one array and add value to another array if checked otherwise remove using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NrSP.png)Following is just the overview of the code,as given in **html code** i just want to show the **options from options array from set object** and **have to set checkbox checked** to option which is **an answer from answer array** and have **to add new answer** to answer if i check more options with checkbox clicked, and have to **remove answer if checkbox is unchecked**.

```js
<script>

var adminApp = angular.module('app',[]);

adminApp.controller('EditController', function ($scope) {

   
     $scope.viewQuestions=function(){

   set={};  //object in which answer array and option array is present //assume;

  var answer= ["answer1", "answer2"]; //answer array assume
 
  var options=["option1,option2,option3,option4"]; //option array assume
  
  var answerType="Multiple";
    }

  $scope.updateAnswer =function(isSet,index,answer,set)
    {
        
        for(var i=0;i<set.answer.length;i++)
        {
              if(isSet===set.answer[i])
              {
                  set.answer[index]=isSet;
              }
              else
              {
               
                set.answer.splice(index, 1);
             
              }
      }
      
   }
   }

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="EditController" ng-init="viewQuestions()">
<table>
<tr>
                                      
 <td ng-show="s.answerType === 'Multiple'">
<p ng-repeat="o in s.options">{{$index + 1}}.  <input type="checkbox" 
name="answer-{{index}}"  
ng-model="isSet"  value="{{o}}"
ng-change="updateAnswer(isSet,$index,answer,s)">{{o}}</p>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is not very clear . what is s ? if you could create a fiddle or something it would be easy

Comment: Ya.i know the code is not very clear..s is actually an object

Comment: i would like to  create a fiddle but actually my object is automatically generated from a docx file and its to big like array of objects so i just put sample s

Comment: Did you check my answer @jayeshmali?

Comment: yes, i did but i need to set active variable only when value in array one is equal to value in array two.Means  I have to set checkbox checked for the value in options array  when value in options array is matching with value in answer array.@joseglego

Comment: please check the image description of mine..u will get an idea.@joseglego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want but it's something. I change the concept to do the same in a cleaner way and more angular style. (in my opinion)

I have an array of objects (`name`: The option title & `active`: Checked or not) And after each change I update the set. With filter & map; So, the set is always up to date

(If you receive a array of string as options, you can assume that all of them are Active: `false`)

Maybe it can works for you in general, or you can get an idea from the code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GucWDwF66A56IkXHHpwG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In **angular**, you can **bind checkbox's checked property to a method** that returns ids of your mini_array that is in main_array;

**---your.html---**

```
enter code here
enter code h
<div class="mb-2"><b>Permissions list</b></div>
<div formArrayName="permissions" *ngFor="let permission of main_array; let i=index">
<input class="mr-2" [checked]="isChecked(permission.id)" type="checkbox">
    {{permission.name}}
</div>
```

**---your.ts---**

```
  isChecked(id) {
    return this.mini_array.includes(id);
  }
```